# can not get the id by using the foreach() and $_POST[]

Tags: php, mysql

okay friends,

I have two tables

1st table: `social_networks`

[image: social_networks table]

2nd table: members_social_accounts

[image: members_social_accounts table]

In the user control panel, I have a page contains a `form` where I list all the social networks; and in a front of each one of them there is an `input` text box.

When the member opens that page, he will see all the social networks listed, and if he previously added his account in any social network, then he will see it in the text box, otherwise, the text box will be empty.  I used the following code to that:

```
$s = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT social_networks.network_id, social_networks.network_name, members_social_accounts.member_account FROM social_networks LEFT JOIN members_social_accounts ON social_networks.network_id = members_social_accounts.network_id AND members_social_accounts.member_id = '$member_id' ORDER BY social_networks.network_id");
while($i = mysqli_fetch_assoc($s)){
    $network_id       = $i['network_id'];
    $network_name     = $i['network_name'];
    $member_account   = $i['member_account'];
}
```

and the input box is:

```
<?=$network_name;?> = <input type="text" name="ids[<?=$network_id;?>]" id="<?=$network_id;?>" value="<?=$member_account;?>" /><br />
```

Now, what I am trying to do is when the user update the page (submit the form), I want the code to update the database by the following steps:

1. `If` the member (e.g. `$member_id =1` ) has already added his account to that network (e.g. `$network_id = 1`) then, we will `UPDATE` the `members_social_accounts` table with the member network account (e.g. `$member_account = 1111111111`).  So, I **DO NOT** add a new record for the same `member_id` and the same `network_id` **but** with different account value.

so, the database table will be something like this:

[image: members_social_accounts after update]

2. `else` if the member (e.g. `$member_id=1`) is adding a new account (e.g. `$member_account = 2222222222`) to a network (e.g. `$network_id = 3`), then I want to `INSERT` that to the `members_social_accounts` table as a new record, and the table will be for example like the following:

[image: members_social_accounts after insert]

What I've tried so far is the following:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST))
{
  foreach($_POST['ids'] AS $ids)
  {
       $s = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM members_social_accounts WHERE network_id = '{$ids}' AND member_id = '$member_id'");
       echo $n = mysqli_num_rows($s);
       if($n == 1)
       {
            // UPDATE the members_social_accounts table
       }
       else
       {
            // INSERT a new record in members_social_accounts table
       }
  }
} 
?>
```

but I have a problem which is that `$_POST[ids] AS $ids` is getting the `member_account` (e.g. `aaaaaaaaaa` and `bbbbbbbbbb`) instead getting the `netword_id` (e.g. `1` and `2`).   Therefore, I am not able to `update` or `insert` in the `members_social_accounts` table.

I appreciate your help in pointing what is wrong with my code or logic.

Thanks in advance

P.S. You can download a copy of the files and the database from this link:
[sample files and db](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4rrjdr7c4yhqd04/AAAVhzymHvTMklLpslbd91-xa?dl=0)

Comment: `foreach($_POST['ids'] AS $network_id => $member_account)`

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that the actual value of your input is the `member_account` field.

```
<input type="text" name="ids[<?=$network_id;?>]" id="<?=$network_id;?>" value="<?=$member_account;?>" />
```

Take a look at the `value` which has been assigned the return from `$member_account` variable.

You could just do:

```
<input type="hidden" name="nid" value="<?=$network_id;?>"/>
```

Then you can do `$_POST['nid']` to get the real value of the `network id`.